# VBA Macro that copies specific cells and sums some of them, and copies them into a different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I need the following,  I looked online but I'm pretty lost...

I need to create one "bottom" that when its "pushed" it opens an existing folder, name "database" and in that folder there are multiple tabs, from the tab "overview" gets this five cells (A23,A24,C23,F42 and F56) and copies them into the origin excel file named "taxes&duties" on the tab "global" in the cells (B24,B46,N45,K56 and K29) it also adds them all together and copies them on L89

I know its very specific and very hard for me, but I'm exhausted of trying and not finding a solution, anyone can help?

Comment: If you want code then you should start writing code. If you don't know VBA then you'll have to learn it. I'd recommend that you start recording the things you want Excel to do for you with the macro recorder: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_HQGHPBYoo Afterwards, have a look at the code and try to understand it by highlighting VBA key-words and pressing `F1`. Also, you might want to read this: http://www.homeandlearn.org/ Then you should be able to provide a first solution to the above problem yourself. If you're still having problems, feel free to come back here and ask for specific advice.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! i will watch the videos!

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function FilePickerFunction$()
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Filters.Clear
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then FilePickerFunction = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
End Function

Sub azert()
With Workbooks.Open(FilePickerFunction)
    ThisWorkbook.Range("MySheet!B24") = .Range("ItsSheet!A23") 'and so on
    ThisWorkbook.Range("MySheet!L89") = .Range("ItsSheet!A23") + ... 'and so on

    .Close
End With
End Sub
```